# Why does pydoc work for some Django folders and not others? How to debug it?

Tags: django, pydoc

I am using Django 4.2, and after setting DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE appropriately, I ran

```
python -m pydoc -b
```

When I visit the pydoc page, a lot of it produces pydoc, even within the modules of my Django project and application. However, occasionally it says:

```
ErrorDuringImport: problem in myapp.mymodule - AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

It says this, for example, in the `admin` module (i.e. `admin.py`).

Why would it work some times and not other times?  I imagine it's some particular import?  How do I figure out which one?